DNS settings not found
does anyone experience google domain and cant view the DNS settings? or view details? Please help
Same also with squarespace i cant find DNS settings
I want to access the DNS settings of my domain
Does anyone can help me with this?
Thanks

To access your domain's DNS settings in Squarespace:

Open your domains dashboard.
Click the domain name. If you have multiple Squarespace domains, you'll manage their DNS records separately.
Click DNS.


Hi , I checked already but still no settings for DNS

It should be have a see details under Action column right? but it my case is does not have

and also i cant view my domain in squarespace , is it because of the transition?
